# Is there an ISO or standardisation covering the YY-MM-DD way of specifying a datetime format

Tags: datetime

So quite a few programming languages (eg c, c#, php, etc.) have adopted a similar way of specifying datetime formats using letters:, eg:

MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss

my question is in two parts:

1.Is this specification even the same between the languages I mention

2.Is there any standardisation of these format definitions (e.g under an ISO) or are these just language specific implementations that sometimes overlap (perhaps because the examples I gave are all c based)?

Comment: You mean, like, ISO-8601?

Comment: that is exactly what i was looking for, thank you - if you want to present as an answer i would happily accept